# Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method in a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a defined function that deletes a sheet and then logs that action to a log file:

```
Public Function DeleteSheet(Wks As Worksheet)

    Wks.Delete
    
    LogInformation ("deleted sheet """ & Wks.Name & """")

End Function
```

However, I am getting the error "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method" When I run the following code, right in the line where the DeleteSheet function is called. What is going on?

```
Dim wks_del_cand As Worksheet ' worksheet delete candidate
    
    Dim names_wks_to_del(1) As String
    names_wks_to_del(0) = "Sheet1"
    names_wks_to_del(1) = "Fred SPS Collat Open Exceptions"
    
    'goes through each of the worksheets in the workbook and deletes any that match the worksheets to delete array
    Dim str As Variant
    For Each wks_del_cand In Wb.Worksheets
        For Each str In names_wks_to_del
            If wks_del_cand.Name = str Then
                
                DeleteSheet (wks_del_cand)
                Exit For

            End If
        Next str
    Next wks_del_cand
```

I have even tried setting up a NEW worksheet object to pass into the function, changing

```
If wks_del_cand.Name = str Then

   DeleteSheet (wks_del_cand)
   Exit For

End If
```

to

```
If wks_del_cand.Name = str Then
    
    Dim wks_to_del As Worksheet
    Set wks_to_del = wks_del_cand
                
    DeleteSheet (wks_to_del)
    Exit For

End If
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick either. Please help!

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parentheses around wks_to_del:

```vb
DeleteSheet wks_to_del
```

I would also suggest changing DeleteSheet from a Function to a Sub as functions in VBA are expected to return a value.

Comment: oh, that's so simple. I even know that needs to be the case but for some reason the wording of the error threw me off!